# Wordpress: Openshift + Cloudflare + Namecheap : Getting Constant Errors

Tags: wordpress, openshift, cloudflare, namecheap

I can't get this combination of tools to work.

**Common Terminology -**

1. Going to use domain.com to describe my domain
2. Going to use prod-domain.rhcloud.com to describe my cloudshift app domain
3. I added a space between https:// & http:// and the domain otherwise stackoverflow wouldnt let me post - that space doesn't exist in reality

**Namecheap**

1. The only 2 name servers in my settings and both are from Cloudflare

**Openshift**

1. I set this up as a scalable application using PHP 5.4, Web Load Balancer, and MySQL 5.5
2. I set up 2 alias's - www.domain.com and domain.com

**Cloudflare:**

*On the DNS Page:*

1. cname for domain.com to prod-domain.rhcloud.com
2. cname for www to prod-domain.rhcloud.com

*On the page rules:*

1. redirects http:// the-domain.com/* to http:// www.the-domain.com/$1 via a 301 redirect

*Other notable settings:*

1. I disabled flexible SSL
2. There are no other A records, I have other cnames pointing to some google short cuts

**Here is what i'm seeing happen:**

1. Going to http:// www.domain.com results in the page loading to the prod-domain.rhcloud.com domain (URL Changes) AND the warning that the page is "trying to load unsafe scripts"
2. Going to http:// domain.com results in an error page "redirected you too many times"
3. Going to https:// www.domain.com results in the page loading to the prod-domain.rhcloud.com domain (URL Changes) AND the warning that the page is "trying to load unsafe scripts"
4. Going to https:// domain.com results in the page loading to the prod-domain.rhcloud.com domain (URL Changes) AND the warning that the page is "trying to load unsafe scripts"

Been banging my head on this for 3 hours and can't get it to work - any suggestions would be more than welcome. I've tried 4 or 5 other guides o stackoverflow and on the web to no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there probably isn't a general suggestion I can provide on this.  You would be advised to contact Cloudflare support so we can provide account specific support.